# Subversive: Difference between depth 'working copy' and 'recursive' when merging?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

When doing a merge using the Subversive plugin for Eclipse, there is an dropdown box named  "depth" where, besides other options, "working copy" and "recursive" can be selected.

I always use the default setting "working copy", but I wonder what the difference between "working copy" and "recursive" is. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It must be similar to the [**depth options** presented in TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html#tsvn-dug-checkout-depth) (also in [merge options](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html)):

- recursive: entire tree, including all child folders and sub-folders
- working copy: Retain the depth specified in the working copy. This option is not used in the checkout dialog, but it is the default in all other dialogs which have a depth setting.

Note: The `--depth` option is new in 1.5 and restricts operation of Subversion subcommands to a certain depth within the target working copy or URL.

This is more detailed than the [Subversion documentation on merge](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/merge_dialog.php).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think the "working copy" options means "take option with which working copy is checked out". If working copy is checked out with "immediate children", then only immediate children will be merged.